# Samsung UJ59 4K with HAMA 122211 cable not working @60Hz

Tags: display, hdmi, lag, 4k-resolution, refresh-rate

I have some hardware issues with my **Samsung UJ59** monitor (4K@60Hz). 
Its connected to my PC using a **HAMA 122211** (600MHz/18Gbps with 3840x2160@60Hz supported).

---

When I'm trying to set the refresh rate on Windows (using **RX560 Saphire Pulse 2Gb**) or Mac (using a MacBook Pro 2018) the maximum rate is between 24Hz and 30Hz.

I can relate this problem on both HDMI ports on the monitor.

---

Why it's not working properly and how to fix it?

Thanks!!

Comment: What HDMI versions does the cable support?  What versions of the HDMI specification does the card support?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment.  **Your hardware (PC) does not support 4k@60Hz by the way.**

Comment: It's working now. Idk why but i'm expecting it was a problem with Generic PnP or smth like that. I just restarted the pc few times and now it's ok on 4k@60hz.